# How to use Airflow AWS connection credentials in Airflow using BashOprator to transfer files from AWS s3 bucket to GCS

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, airflow, rsync

As I am working with two clouds, My task is to rsync files coming into s3 bucket to gcs bucket. To achieve this I am using GCP composer (Airflow) service where I am scheduling this rsync operation to sync files. I am using Airflow connection (aws_default) to store AWS access key and secret access key. Everything is working fine but thing is that I am able to see credentials in logs which is again exposing credentials and I don't want to display them even in logs. Please assist if there is any way so that credentials should not display in logs.

```
import airflow
import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash_operator import BashOperator
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from datetime import timedelta, datetime

START_TIME = datetime.utcnow() - timedelta(hours=1)

default_args = {
    'owner': 'airflow',
    'depends_on_past': True,
    'wait_for_downstream': True,
    'start_date': START_TIME,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 3,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=3)
}

aws_connection = BaseHook.get_connection('aws_default')

bash_env = {
        "AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID": aws_connection.login,
        "AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY": aws_connection.password
}

rsync_command = ''' 
    set -e; 
    export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID="%s"; 
    export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY="%s"; 
''' %(bash_env.get('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), bash_env.get('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY')) \
+  '''
    gsutil -m rsync -r -n s3://aws_bucket/{{ execution_date.strftime('%Y/%m/%d/%H') }}/ gs://gcp_bucket/good/test/
'''

dag = DAG(
    'rsync',
    default_args=default_args,
    description='This dag is for gsutil rsync from s3 buket to gcs storage',
    schedule_interval=timedelta(minutes=20),
    dagrun_timeout=timedelta(minutes=15)
    )


s3_sync = BashOperator(
    task_id='gsutil_s3_gcp_sync',
    bash_command=rsync_command,
    dag=dag,
    depends_on_past=False,
    execution_timeout=timedelta(hours=1),
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest putting the credentials in a boto config file separate from Airflow. More info on config file [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil/commands/config#configuration-file-selection-procedure)

It has a credential section:

```
[Credentials]
  aws_access_key_id
  aws_secret_access_key
  gs_access_key_id
  gs_host
  gs_host_header
  gs_json_host
  gs_json_host_header
  gs_json_port
  gs_oauth2_refresh_token
  gs_port
  gs_secret_access_key
  gs_service_client_id
  gs_service_key_file
  gs_service_key_file_password
  s3_host
  s3_host_header
  s3_port
```

Comment: I understand this but our Airflow service is running on GCP cloud composer which is managed service by google ( Backend kubernetes ), not on VM. In this case how can I configure credentials in .boto file.

Comment: When using Docker or k8s It's really common to create configuration files including env variables using secrets and/or entrypoints. [here](https://www.magalix.com/blog/kubernetes-configuration-management-101) is an article on this topic.

Comment: I too am running Airflow on Cloud Composer and can't use a boto file to store config